# How can I ignore all of the rows that come before a successful login in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In order to block a user in my application after a certain amount of failed attempts, I'm using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(user) as cant
FROM mo_bitacora
WHERE d_accion = 'failed' 
and f_registro between (now() -INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) and now() 
and usuario = 'user'
```

This counts how many failed attempts the user has got in 30 minutes. The thing is that if the user does a successful login and then log out and then make another failed attempt, his user will be blocked. This is a pretty rare scenario but still an unwanted behavior.

How can I ignore all of the rows that come before a successful login?

Succesfull login saves in this table as a 'succesfull' on d_accion.
Table binnacle has the following columns:

```
usuario varchar(45) 
f_registro datetime 
d_accion varchar(45) 
d_direccion_ip varchar(45)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a status flag to tell the system if these failed login are to be taken into account:

```
SELECT COUNT(user) as cant
FROM mo_bitacora
WHERE d_accion = 'failed' 
and f_registro between (now() -INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) and now() 
and usuario = 'user'
and status=0
```

Edit your table to include the status field that default to 1 (failed login to be counted) and turns to 0 (failed login not to be counted) when the user does a successful login.
This will keep you the history of this logins.